# Is there a way to get the latest version of microsoft edge for linux?

Tags: bash, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm currently trying to write a bash script that downloads the latest version which almost works:

```
edge_driver_version=$(curl -s https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/LATEST_STABLE | iconv -c -f utf-8 | tr -d '\0\r')

wget -F "https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/${edge_driver_version}/edgedriver_linux64.zip" -P $install_dir
```

The main issue I'm running into is with getting the version from:  https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/LATEST_STABLE

This returns the latest version for windows and isn't available for Linux. Is there an equivalent link I can use to get the Linux version?

Comment: One unreliable method: `edge_driver_version=$(curl -s https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/ | grep -Pzo 'aria-label="Linux[^"]+stable channel[^"]+?\K[\d.]+')`

Comment: btw, input is utf16le not utf-8, but you could replace iconv+tr with just `| tr -cd 0-9.`

Comment: Think this is the best I'll get for now, thank you!